# How can I define scripts in CakePHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, prototypejs

Whenever I am trying to define 2 scripts this way:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery', 'prototype'));
```

only `prototype` is working.

When I do it this way:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array('prototype', 'jquery'));
```

only `jquery` is working.

How do I fix it so both are working?

Comment: the question is: why are you including both jQuery and Prototype? The answers suggesting `.noConflict()` are correct, but you'll still have problems if you're expecting code to work with `$()` for both libraries.

Comment: @Spudley I need prototype to finish autocomplete functionality in my cake application and I need jquery to manipulate DOM :(

Comment: Prototype is also capable of manipulating the DOM, and jQuery has autocomplete plug-ins.

Comment: Well I will just need to learn it. For now I will have to stick using both at the same time. But thanks for the comment anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because they **both** use the `$` variable, and the second script overwrites the first.

Try creating a script for the middle that only contains:

```
$j = $.noConflict(); //sets `$j` as the jQuery variable
```

Then do:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery', 'middleScript', 'prototype'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>` immediately after jQuery, and *then* add prototype.